# Cryptanalytic attacks ASCON MAC

Tags: cryptanalysis, mac, authenticated-encryption

I am researching ASCON. I can find cryptanalytic attacks ASCON authenticated encryption and ASCON HASH, But I am not finding anything ASCON MAC. Anyone knows of any attacks, any research on this?

Comment: Maybe compose the proof of indistinguishability of ASCON permutation with Sponge MAC mode of operation? Or decompose that of ASCON AE into parts of encryption and authentication?

Comment: Hi @DannyNiu please explain a little more.

Comment: Composing: There're probably other permutation-based MAC schemes, use their proof for the mode of operation with indistinguishability proof for ASCON would yield a proof for ASCON-MAC. Decomposing: Just ignore the encryption part (by e.g. disclosing the plaintext) and adopt the proof for ASCON-AE for ASCON-MAC. I'm not well-versed mathematically, so I can only provide a general idea, and not a full answer.

Comment: Yep, exactly what I wanted to post yesterday. For these kind of schemes normally the construction is *proven* to be secure assuming that the primitive is secure. And the primitive (ASCON) is then *shown* to be secure using analytic attacks. That I know how this works doesn't mean that I know how to do it necessarily though :|

Comment: There are [lots](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1574) of Ascon variants/[uses](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/391) and not all of them have been directly analysed by a third party. I looked at Ascon during my dissertation earlier this year and don't remember seeing any papers analysing Ascon-MAC. Also, it differs from the AEAD mode, like it doesn't do [key blinding](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/796). It's more similar to Ascon-Hash. It's worth looking at the NIST Lightweight Cryptography Workshops for presentations that summarise the security analysis results of the permutation.